# On the multivariable Taylor expansion

Tags: multivariable-calculus, taylor-expansion

Apparently the second order multivariable Taylor expansion is: $$f(\mathbf x+\mathbf h)=f(\mathbf x)+ \partial_i f(\mathbf x) h_i + \frac 12 \partial_j \partial_i f(\mathbf x + t \mathbf h) h_i h_j$$ for some $t$, $0 \le t \le 1$, where some twice differentiable $f$ is defined in some neighborhood $N(x) \subset \Bbb R^n$ and $(\mathbf x + \mathbf h) \in N(x)$, and using the Einstein summation convention.

Am I right then in thinking that the entire (infinite order?) Taylor expansion is:
$$f(\mathbf x+\mathbf h)=\sum_{i=0}^\infty \frac 1 {i!}[\partial]_i f(\mathbf x) [h]_i$$
where I'm using the notation (which I just invented) $[\partial]_k=\underbrace{\partial_i \partial_j \cdots}_{k\text{ of these}}$ and likewise for $[h]_i$?  If so, what happened to the $+ t\mathbf h$ part?  If not, what's the actual formula?

Comment: Where are you using the summation convention? I don't see any upper indices.

Comment: @RobinGoodfellow I'm using the convention as it's used in undergrad classes where there are ONLY lower indices and any term with 2 of the same index is summed over that index.  I've seen the notation you're thinking of, but that's differential geometry, I think, and I haven't gotten there, yet.

Comment: @gotit--thanks There are notations for this already; They are
$$f(x+h) = \sum_{i=0}^\infty \frac1{i!} \sum_{|\alpha| = i} \partial^\alpha f(x) \prod_{j=1}^n h_{\alpha_j}$$
But this is incorrect.

Comment: @gotit--thanks No, the factorial must be a multiindex factorial:
$$\alpha! = \prod_{j=1}^n \alpha_j!$$

Comment: @MusséRedi The higher order terms don't appear because I used a [mean-value form of the remainder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor%27s_theorem#Explicit_formulas_for_the_remainder) (thus the "$+t\mathbf h$ for some $t\in [0,1]$" part).  So stop trying to edit it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct taylor formula is
$$f(x+h) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \sum_{|\alpha| = k} \frac1{\alpha!} \partial^\alpha f(x) h^\alpha$$
Where for a multiindex $\alpha\in\mathbb N_0^n$
$$\alpha! = \prod_{j=1}^n \alpha_j!\\
x^\alpha = \prod_{j=1}^n x_j^{\alpha_j}\\
\partial^\alpha = \prod_{j=1}^n \frac{\partial^{\alpha_j}}{\partial x_j^{\alpha_j}}$$
Or even shorter
$$f(x+h) = \sum_{\alpha\in\mathbb N_0^n} \frac1{\alpha!} \partial^\alpha f(x) h^\alpha$$

Unfortunately I can only provide [a reference](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/TaylorSeries.html) for the $n=1$ case ($f:\mathbb R^m \to\mathbb R^n$) and [a wikipedia reference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor%27s_theorem#Taylor.27s_theorem_for_multivariate_functions) for the general case.